# How can i create jar file?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, jar

I have a mobile application project. I convert it as a jar file with Intellij Idea. But there is nothing in the jar file. How exactly can I create the jar file? I researched on the internet and found out in the sources that it can also be done via terminal, but I am getting errors with that method as well. Can you help me?

My other question is this: Am I considered to have hidden the source code when I convert it to a jar file? So when I give this file to someone else, I don't want them to receive the source code.

Comment: Android doesn't use jar files for apps. Why do you think you need a jar?

Comment: I developed a project that can communicate via Bluetooth. I will give the methods in this project to someone else so they can use them in their own project. @g00se

Comment: Android apps are deployed as apk files normally

Comment: And Android library projects are usually provided in aar format.

Comment: @g00se Can I add the apk file to the project? Is it possible to access the methods in an apk file?

Comment: @Robert How can I convert it to AAR format? Also, will aar format work for my problem? Will it be possible to access methods without seeing the source codes from the external project? Just like DLL logic in C#.

Comment: Sounds like you want to actually create a shared library. I'm going to leave that to someone else as I don't do Android. I'm going to guess that there might be an intermediate form without creating an actual .so file

Comment: @g00se Thank you for your opinion. I hope somebody else can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the project from Application type to Library type in the gradle file and exported it in aar format. I was able to export it by hiding the source code. My problem is solved. Thanks to Robert for presenting this idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the app before creating the .jar

I don't know if it is possible to hide the code 100%, since it is possible to decompile the code.